# Determine which folder a message is in

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Outlook, I do a Search on `All Mailboxes` and I get a list of messages. These messages can be in different folders. How can I determine, for a given message in the list, which folder it is in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you **hover** over an email, you should see a tiny popup window that tells you which folder it is in. I just tried it and I'm using the latest version of outlook.

[image]